# Google Places Autocomplete Remove State and Country from Result

Tags: google-places-api

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

I have a page similar to the above google places autocomplete demo url whereby if i type Buckingham Palace. It will return results of

1. Buckingham Palace Road, London, United Kingdom
2. Buckingham Palace Shop, Buckingham Palace Road, Victoria, London,
   United Kingdom

and etc. How do i remove London, United Kingdom from the results?

Comment: I wrote a [blog post related to this question](http://rustamagasanov.com/blog/2014/09/04/google-places-limit-autocomplete-results-to-cities-only/), it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without manually processing the results. If you think that it would be a useful feature, please file a [Places API - Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Answer (score 3):

It seems Google have no interest in sorting it out anytime soon. I have had to resort to the following, might be sufficient for others' needs as well:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.hasClass('pac-item')) {
        target.html(target.html().replace(/, Australia<\/span>$/, "</span>"));
    }
});
```

note that `pac-item` is the class used on each suggestion. See [Google Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete) for other classes used. The container with `pac-container` class seems to drop the items when it is not shown and add new ones when it displays so if these `pac-items` are getting added to the DOM, it means suggestions are on their way to be displayed and `pac-container` is about to become visible.

just worked this out so open to improvements.

This also is not a complete solution. When selecting a suggestion with the country removed, autocomplete still adds the country to the geocoding! `place_changed` is too late a stage to change that so please see the solution above as only part of the answer. I'll update this again once I figure out the rest.

--- update

personally, i ended up not using the google autocomplete at all as i couldn't find a way around the problem of the autocomplete still showing the country once a modified suggestion is selected. a more usable approach was to use twitter typeahead and use the google APIs for getting the suggestions only. this gave me more control over the suggestions but obviously requires more manual work to make up for lost functionality

Comment: Great job bro..!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is How I made it work with jQuery auto-complete. Hope it helps someone.

```
   $("#Search").autocomplete({
       source: function (request, response) {
           var options = {
               input: request.term,
               types: ['(cities)'],
               region: 'US',
               componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }
           };
           function callback(predictions, status) {
               for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
                   results.push(prediction.description.replace(/, United States$/, ""));
               }
               response(results);
           }
           var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
           service.getPlacePredictions(options, callback);
           var results = [];
       }
   });
```