# Google places AutoComplete limit types & hide key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, grails, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a simple grails application which has an autocomplete input field which uses the google places api. The code is as follows

```
<label for="city">
   <input id="city" name="city">
</label>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=myKey"></script>
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('city');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
</script>
```

This works fine, but this provides information such as city,state,country. I only require city and state/ only state, I do not want the country.

```
Boston, MA, United States - Is the results that I get and i Need it to look like

Boston, MA Or MA
```

Is there a way to add a template to the response I get? (I require city and state from all over the world, but with no country in the response)

I'm new to this API, Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have 2 questions here.  Please ask about protecting the key in a separate question so it can be answered separately.

Comment: Done, modified my question. The other question is in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657161/google-places-autocomplete-hide-key)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can filter your `google-map search` results to particular country pretty easily.

Just pass an `option` to your Autocomplete function like below

```
 //options for restricting the search result to "US"
 var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
 };

 //Search box code
 var input = document.getElementById('city');
 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

> Official Country Code Reference :
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#AM

As Vishal has mentioned that he wants search to produce only cities over the whole world, I am afraid but **google map has no such facility to give only the city names of all the countries in search result**.

One thing we can do is change the input value(Remove country from it) after 
user select the address.

Add below code  :

```
 //Search box code
 var input = document.getElementById('city');
 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

 //adding event listener over the input box
 google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = searchBox.getPlace();

        //remove the country part from search result
        var rquiredAddress = place.formatted_address.slice(0, place.formatted_address.lastIndexOf(","));;
       $("#city").val(rquiredAddress);
 });
```

> Just an opinion, you should keep the country part in search as there
>   might be number of city names similar in different countries and it
>   will confuse user.

Comment: My requirement is not restricted to one country. I did find this solution when I was doing a bit of research. I require to get city and state of countries all over the world. Just that I do not want the country name in the results. Initially I used gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity api which has a template parameter where we can set city and state as the response needed. But it had a mixed context loading issue so I am looking at google places api. Currently I'm trying to find a parameter to the request similar to the one from geobytes, if any.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Its not exactly what you are looking for but way around.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not yet available through API. You can only do this manually or creating a function that filter the API response to your customize text.

References:

- [Google Places Autocomplete Remove State and Country from Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288593/google-places-autocomplete-remove-state-and-country-from-result)
- [Google Places: Limit Autocomplete Results to Cities Only, Hints](http://rustamagasanov.com/blog/2014/09/04/google-places-limit-autocomplete-results-to-cities-only/)
- [Google Places JavaScript Autocomplete: can I remove the country from the place name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626727/google-places-javascript-autocomplete-can-i-remove-the-country-from-the-place-n)

Also you can check [Places API Feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:PlacesAPI%20type:Enhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) to see if there is already a pending Feature request for this. If not you can file a [Feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Hope this helps!