# Google places AutoComplete hide key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a grails application. In my gsp page when I have the line

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=myKey"></script>
```

My key is exposed, is there a way to hide this in the gsp? I could restrict the domain for my production, but currently the application is being tested in my local machine alot, and because of that each PC's ip has to be added. I'm assuming there should be a smarter & easier way to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to hide this line. However, you can restrict the domain which uses the specified key in google api control panel.

[Login from here](https://console.developers.google.com)

Click *Credentials* from left section. Find your key in *API KEYS* panel.

[image]

**After That**

Choose *HTTP referrers (web sites)* and enter your domain into textfield and save. Pay attention Google's note below.

Note: It may take up to 5 minutes for settings to take effect

[image]

Comment: As by editing the question, I have mentioned that I did come across this, but it will not be very useful when i'm developing this locally. Specially when I use multiple machines from different ip's. I'm wondering there should be a way because, for more than 150000 requests per day, the customer is expected to pay. So if a payed key is exposed, that would mean anyone can use it, unless it's restricted like you have mentioned. This solution doesn't seem really developer friendly. Hoping for a method to hide the key

Comment: You can add multiple web sites. Add "localhost:portnumber" to website textfield.

Comment: You can also, and actually absolutely *should*, have an API key exclusively for your production site/s, and others for your internal development environment. You might even want to use separate API projects one day (production one with billing enabled, development one without).