# How to get only city name without country using google place API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I want only city name without country using `google` place API

For that I used `react-places-autocomplete`

I tried
`types: ['(cities)']`
But it returns "Newyork, NY, USA" instead of "Newyork, NY"

I just want "Newyork, NY".

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to remove country name from Place Autocomplete suggestions at this time.

However, there is an open feature request in Google's Issue Tracker which I suggest starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822039

Also check out this related thread for potential workarounds:
[Google Places Autocomplete Remove State and Country from Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288593/google-places-autocomplete-remove-state-and-country-from-result)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

### Feature Added on **Sep 2022**

For anyone looking to find a solution for like me, I found out that this feature has been added into the API as mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824093#comment7)

> Good news! This feature is now available in the [weekly channel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#release-channels-and-version-numbers).
>
> To try this out, modify
> https://jsbin.com/qoxiwawuno/edit?html,js,output to set `region=us` (and
> add your API), then for instance typing "paris" will show
>
> - Paris, France
> - Paris, TX (no country name)

You can do so like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=API_KEY&callback=loadAutocomlete&libraries=places&region=fr&v=weekly" async ></script>
```